# How to use private class fields in nodejs 12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, private, class-fields

In the current release of *nodejs* **i.e.** `12.x.x`, we can declare `private` class fields by the `#some_varible` notation. The `#` notation would make the variable private field for that particular class.

```
class Foo {
  #some_varible = 10;
}
```

**I have the following Questions:**

- How to use this variable?
- Is it safe to use such notations in a production app for declaring private class fields?
- How does it work in background (in nodejs), when some class field is declared private?

Comment: This article answers the first two questions nicely: https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-private-class-fields.html

Comment: and why is that `#` used instead of `private ` ??

Comment: @messerbill you can find the probable answer to your question [here](https://jamie.build/javascripts-new-private-class-fields.html), though i am not sure about its correctness.

Comment: thank you for this

Comment: Please show us the research you've done.

Comment: I have read blogs related to usage as suggested by others, but didn't find any content related to the backgroud process that happens

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to use this variable?

You can use it as a backing field for an accessor property:

```js
class Foo {
  #some_variable = 10;
  
  get some_variable () {
    console.log('getting some_variable');
    return this.#some_variable;
  }
  
  set some_variable (value) {
    console.log('setting some_variable');
    this.#some_variable = value;
  }
}

let bar = new Foo();

console.log(bar.some_variable);
console.log(bar.some_variable = 42);
```

Or you can use it like a normal property, the main difference being that it can only be accessed from within the `class { ... }` scope, since it is private, and that the property is prefixed with a `#`.

Also note that `this.#some_variable` is *not* the same as `this['#some_variable']`, the latter of which refers to the string property, not the private field.

> Is it safe to use such notations in a production app for declaring private class fields?

The answer is *it depends*.

With client-side JavaScript, you have no control over the executing environment, but you can transform new language features such as private class fields into functional equivalents relying only on syntax from older language specifications using [Babel plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-private-methods).

In Node.js, you *do* have control over the executing environment, so to use new language features, just ensure you're using [a version that supports the syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Browser_compatibility).

> How does it work in background (in nodejs), when some class field is declared private?

### V8 implementation

Private fields use block-scoped [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) which are blacklisted from the reflection method [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols).

[image: native implementation]

Here's what a transformed class emulating this implementation might look like:

```js
let Foo;

{
  const some_variable = Symbol('#some_variable');

  {
    const getOwnPropertySymbolsImpl = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols;
    Object.getOwnPropertySymbols = function getOwnPropertySymbols () {
      return getOwnPropertySymbolsImpl.apply(this, arguments)
        .filter(symbol => symbol !== some_variable);
    };
  }

  Foo = class Foo {
    [some_variable] = 10;
  };
}

let bar = new Foo();
console.log(bar);
```

This produces a very similar-looking output to the native implementation:

[image: polyfill implementation]

---

### Babel implementation

#### [`@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Private fields are stored as a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) where each entry is a class instance key and its respective private field [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) value.

Here's how Babel transforms the class we've been using as an example:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    _some_variable.set(this, {
      writable: true,
      value: 10
    });
  }
}

var _some_variable = new WeakMap();
```

Note that while `_some_variable` is not block-scoped here, Babel will ensure that the name in the transformed output does not collide with any visible names in that scope, so the weak map is inaccessible from within the pre-compiled source.

Comment: Whoa,thanks! that really helped understand the concept.