# Error using a generator function as value of a WeakMap

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-generator

I'm building a linked list by my own. I tried to assign a generator as value of a key/value WeakMap in the constructor. The `_iterator` is a WeakMap because is a private member that I want use to make simple iterate over my data structure, but I don't want make the generator visible outside because otherwise I'll break abstraction. But I have the error `SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters`. What is the problem?

```
  class Node{
     constructor(value){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
     }
  }

  //IIFE function that return the class. 
  const SingleLinkedList = (() => { //Here use IIFE to create a new block scope for private variables
     let _counts = new WeakMap();
     let _head = new WeakMap();
     let _tail = new WeakMap();
     let _iterator = new WeakMap();

     class SingleLinkedList {
        constructor() {
           _counts.set(this, 0);
           _head.set(this, null);
           _tail.set(this, null);
           let instance = this;//closure
           _iterator.set(this,(function* [Symbol.iterator](){
              let n=_head.get(instance);
              while(n){
                 yield n;
                 n = n.next;
              }
           }));
        }


        get counts() { //read only get accessor property
           return _counts.get(this);
        }

        isEmpty() {
           return !this.counts;  //or return !_head.get(this)
        }

        //insert a new Node (in tail) with the desired value
        push(value) {
           let n = new Node(value);
           if (this.isEmpty()) 
              _head.set(this, n);
           else {
              let tail = _tail.get(this); //tail is a pointer to the node-tail
              tail.next = n; //old tail-node will point to new node
           }

           //the following instructions are common to both the cases.
           _tail.set(this, n); //set new tail
           _counts.set(this, this.counts+1); //increment item counter

           return this; //to allow multiple push call
        }

        //Generator to return the values
        *[Symbol.iterator](){

           let n = _head.get(this); 
           while(n){
              yield n.value;
              n=n.next;
           }
        }
        //the the values of each node
        print() {
           let output = "";
           for(let el of this)
              output += `${el} `;
           console.log(output);
        }
     }
     return SingleLinkedList;
  })();

  let myLinkedList = new SingleLinkedList();
  myLinkedList.push(3);
  myLinkedList.push(5);
  myLinkedList.print();

  /*for(let x of myLinkedList)
     console.log(x);*/
```

Comment: i see a problem here `function* [Symbol.iterator]()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function expressions can't have computed names, that syntax is only allowed on object literal members or class members, so define the constructor of your `SingleLinkedList` like this instead:

```
constructor() {
  _counts.set(this, 0);
  _head.set(this, null);
  _tail.set(this, null);
  let instance = this;//closure
  _iterator.set(this, function* (){
// remove the computed name ---^
    let n=_head.get(instance);
    while(n){
      yield n;
      n = n.next;
    }
  });
}
```

Perhaps even more useful is knowing how to debug syntax errors in the future so you don't need to ask questions like this again. If you open your developer console by pressing F12, you'll see a log that looks something like this:

[image: SyntaxError in developer console]

Click that link and it will take you straight to the location of the error:

[image: SyntaxError in debugger]

---

Just for fun, here's my suggested rewrite using some more modern features of ECMAScript like [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_instance_fields):

```js
class Node {
  next = null;

  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class SingleLinkedList {
  #size = 0;
  #head = null;
  #tail = null;

  // read only get accessor property
  get size () {
    return this.#size;
  }

  isEmpty () {
    return this.#size === 0;
  }

  // insert a new Node (in tail) with the desired value
  push (value) {
    const node = new Node(value);

    if (this.isEmpty()) {
      this.#head = node;
    } else {
      this.#tail.next = node;
    }

    // the following instructions are common to both the cases.
    this.#tail = node;
    this.#size++;

    // to allow multiple push call
    return this;
  }

  // generator to return the values
  *[Symbol.iterator] () {
    for (let current = this.#head; current; current = current.next) {
      yield current.value;
    }
  }

  // the the values of each node
  toString () {
    return [...this].join(' ');
  }
}

const myLinkedList = new SingleLinkedList();
myLinkedList.push(3).push(5);
console.log(myLinkedList.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't remember this constraint. The generator is already an iterable. Now, it works.

Comment: I have appreciated a lot your code. I partially knew the news about classes and private members but they were at proposal, draft stage. Furthermore I know there is Babel but at the moment I'm not in production phase(I've been learning Javascript for two or three months, I come from the pure world OOP) and I prevent to get stuck with webpack and so on. However now I read that Google now  is equipped with private class fields and I'm going to use them, the code becomes much readable and intuitive. Thanks again.

Comment: @Umbert fair enough. I'd personally avoid using private class fields if you're not transpiling, since I'm not aware of any browser besides Chrome that currently supports them even though they're standardized. You were spot-on using `WeakMap` in a closure, and in fact that's how [babel implements private fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57997578/1541563).